# MongoDB findOneAndUpdate(): Update with partial input

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a simple MongoDB document, whose mongoose schema is:

```js
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  a: Number,
  b: Number,
  c: Number
});
```

And my current DB looks like:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": 3
  }
]
```

I want to `findOneAndUpdate`, and give only as input a partial document, like `{ b: 4 }`, `{ c: 5 }`, or `{}`. And the document should only update the fields that are in the input, leaving other fields intact.

Some Examples

#### Input: `{ b: 4 }`

Replaced document should look like:

```
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "a": 1,
    "b": 4,
    "c": 3
  }
```

#### Input: `{}`

Replaced document should not change:

```
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2,
    "c": 3
  }
```

#### Current behavior

With the below code:

```
const data = { b: 4 };

User.findOneAndUpdate(
  { a: 1 },
  { $set: { b: data.b, c: data.c } }
);
```

I get the following result:

```
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "a": 1,
    "b": 4,
  }
```

Whereas expected would be:

```
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "a": 1,
    "b": 4,
    "c": 3
  }
```

How would I change my code?

Answer (score 0):

By saying this where `data.c` is `undefined`,

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(
  { a: 1 },
  { $set: { b: data.b, c: data.c } }
);
```

you are telling mongodb to actually remove `undefined` the property.

You should do like this:

```
const data = { b: 4 };

User.findOneAndUpdate(
  { a: 1 },
  { $set: data }
);
```